# What is an option inside a tag called in XML?

Tags: html, xml, terminology

Take this piece of XML:

```
<foo bar='biz'></foo>
```

What is the `bar` value called? This seems like it should be obvious, but I realized that even with the amount of XML and HTML I have used I do not know what such values are formally reffered to as. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I worry about such questions. Is StackOverflow your only source of information about XML? It concerns me that someone should be using XML entirely by trial and error, without having read even a basic introduction to the concepts. It's good that you should ask, but if you need to ask this question, then there are a lot of other things you should know before you use this technology.

Comment: The problem with the question is that it does not clearly identify what is being asked; “the `bar` value” is a rather obscure expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct `bar='biz'` as a whole is called *attribute specification* (often informally *attribute* for short), and the `'biz`' part is *attribute value* (it is not clear from the question which one you mean). Ref. [XML 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

Answer (score -1):

It is called attribute.

Google is usually best for such answers:
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=xml+attributes

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I don't quite understand your comment. I did NOT suggest to use w3schools for ALL education but just pointed to an article that answered a question. Was the answer provided incorrect or misleading in any way? Or is it just the reference that is troubling you?

Comment: Citing w3schools.com is bad, for reasons explained at http://w3fools.com. The specific page linked to id bad, too, starting from the very first tag there (an invalid `img` tag). And the answer is wrong as regards to the official name of the construct.

Comment: Revisiting this after years reminds me what is wrong with SO. I asked this when I was very young and inexperienced (14 or 15) and was chastised because I didn't know the terminology. What the terminology was is _exactly_ what I was asking. Linking to a Google search is not helpful - I could not search for something I did not know the name of, and I had no teacher besides online resources. Would I still ask this question today? No. I would go and read an overview until I found the term I didn't know. But this community's attitude towards beginners worries me.